# How to lock app folder on iOS 8.1.2?

Tags: ios, ipod-touch, ipod

We are trying discontinue our user's use of iPod touch devices in production.

We want users only use certain apps. The rest of the apps should be hidden or locked.

I tried "Restrictions" from "General" in "Settings", it only hides few icons. I put all not-to-use icons into one folder and tried to lock it or hide it, but haven't found any way that works on iOS 8.1.2 or 8.1.3.

Is there any way to hide or lock applications or folders?

Comment: You can't. You can only filter apps that are displayed by category. (I.e., 4+ 17+ etc)

Comment: I see there are something called [ios for enterprise] that can  customize device based on requirements....but there is a cost for it.....apple just makes things so difficult